# Build Play Music-like interface

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android

I'm trying to build and interface that would mimic the recent Google Play Music interface which as a reminder looks like this on a phone

[image: google play music interface]

I've already got the `DrawerLayout` and the Tabs right, but I have no idea how to build the amazing bottom fragment that displays the currently playing song. It mixes two features:

- If you swipe this fragment to the left, it will be replaced by the next song. i think it can be done fairly quickly using a `ViewPager` and a new `Fragment`for each song, but is it an efficient way to do it?
- If you swipe it up, it will open kind of a drawer containing the player itself (see the above second and third screenshots). How can I get something similar inside my application? I can't find any mention of this inside the docs so I guess it's not really official.

Comment: Hey, are you able to achieve this interface successfully?  I am also looking for the same, can you please answer over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274623/how-to-show-mini-controller-at-bottom-or-persistent-media-controls-like-spotify

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Use [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library. It is pretty easy to use.
- Add a [FragmentPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) inside this panel for the "Swipe left for the next song" feature. It also can be the "handle" for sliding up panel.
- Add the player layout inside the sliding up panel layout

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Yet when I put a ViewPager inside the ASUPanel, the ViewPager isn't swipable anymore.

Comment: @ThuyTrinh You can try to setEnableDragViewTouchEvents(true);

Comment: Is there any native way to do it without the library

Answer (score 1):

Here is extention to Minas answer How to make that slidingup panel to stay in all the fragments

Two approaches for this are (assuming you're using SlidingUpPanelLayout by sothree)

- **With bottom navigation view**
  Easy way to do it is creating a bottom navigation view and keeping it in MainActivity and attaching the sliding up panel layout to the bottom navigation view ( `layout_above = bottomnavbar_id` ) since bottom navigation stays throughout the app so sliding up panel will also have to stay with it
  example:

  ```
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"

       tools:context=".MainActivity"

       >

       <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/slidingup"
           android:gravity="bottom"
           android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"<!--Here-->
           >

           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:id="@+id/fragview"
               >

           </RelativeLayout>


           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"

               >


           </RelativeLayout>



       </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>



       <com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar
           android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
           app:cnb_menuResource="@menu/bottom_navigation_bar"
           app:cnb_unselectedColor="@color/white"
           app:cnb_radius="40dp"
           app:cnb_iconSize="34dp"
           android:elevation="8dp"
           />
  ```
- **Without bottom navigation view**
  Create a frame layout inside MainActivity give attributes width and height as `match_parent` and create slidinguppanelayout and give attributes `gravity="bottom"`
  make the frame layout stay above that slidinguppanellayout , use that `frame_layout` to show content your want to show from fragments

that's all