# Sliding Card Design

Tags: android, user-interface

I am looking for some ideas on how to best achieve this effect. I have two fragments, one containing the map (and all controls) and another fragment that contains my RecyclerView to display the results. In my activity layout I would like to position my map and list fragments exactly how it is shown in [this video](http://youtu.be/c36MGtG6hlM). The map fragment shall stay aligned with the topmost edge of the list unless the user is actively scrolling the list upwards. The video I recorded should demonstrate what it is I am trying to achieve.

From an explanatory standpoint, I need view and layout ideas. I have already implemented all the necessary callbacks for all user interactions between the two fragments and the activity. One item in particular I am most interested hearing feedback on is how to align two views and then have the lower slide over the view when the user starts scrolling. Notice how the list (when showing) will not scroll downward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method I can suggest is to have both the map and the ListView in the same fragment and try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658058/build-play-music-like-interface). It's the sliding drawer animation in Play Music.

For the part where touching the map shrinks the list view to a bar on the bottom. I suggest you create animations in the listView to shrink and to expand and call them on event Down and Up respectively. Here is the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).