# How to have a list of cards that can swipe under other cards, like notification cards on locksreen of lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, slide, android-cardview

I want to show a list of items, that can have the items slide under one another like the items on the lockscreen of Lollipop when it is slided up.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735096/sliding-card-design) page?

Comment: @Razor no, I want items of list to slide under each other.

Comment: Do you want to allow the user to swipe them or will they swipe automatically?

Comment: @Razor automatic swipe. no user interaction.

Comment: The only swipe functionality that is available is with user interaction. You may have to use animations to animate the swiping effect if you want it to happen automatically.