# Android: How to create music player?

Tags: android, listview, audio-player, android-music-player

How to set every page in show bottom this type layout?
One Page in to manage play and stop song.

[image]

Comment: please explain your question,, its vague

Comment: the best thing should be to use fragments.. in this way your one part of screen will be persisted and the rest should be fragments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658058/build-play-music-like-interface please see the link. how to create same this type of music player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the Bottom Bar in `Activity` and should have `Fragments` for other layout in your activity.

Here is the great tutorial to implement **Music Player** in Android from scratch : [Create a Music Player on Android](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764).

Another cool feature  : [Android Sliding Up Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) imitates the same feature as Google Play Music with sliding up Current Playing Music.

[image: Android Sliding Up Panel]

Comment: Hello. I have some problem. download and import project in android studio.

Comment: Please explain your problem you are facing. Rather i would suggest you to understand the concept from tutorial and try implementing it by own. If you still need help, then of-course you have source code to that project and open its source code in any Editor for code/Activity's proper implementation.

Comment: your project github to download. and import in android studio. but some file not found. error

Comment: show your screen in bottom music player. how to create this type player? and show every pages like Activity and fragment.

Comment: Firstly its not mine GitHub project, i just provided you with the solution. Second i already described you that you have to implement bottom bar in activity and host fragments with other corresponding layouts.

Comment: you are right. but how to create bottom bar layout ? and bottom bar layout show in every activity.

Comment: Using `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` as root view and subsequently adding elements according to your use (Play/Pause Button, TextView etc.)in your main activity. And as per my suggestion start with implementing small modules first. I think you are new to android so first implement basic things.

Comment: But I have Five activity. show bottom bar layout in fifth activity. after show all other acitivty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658058/build-play-music-like-interface  please see the link. and create same layout

Answer (score 0):

You can change the view by setVisibility(View.GONE/View.VISIBLE/View.INVISIBLE) along with FrameLayout.
Another way, learn about the fragments. Hope you'll find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```